# Handling some custom validation in a spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, microservices

Suppose I have a validation function found in a userAuthService, necessary in every function of an OrderService

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/", ""}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrders(@RequestHeader(value="userID") String userID) {
    boolean validUser = userAuthService.validateUserByID(userID);

    if(validUser) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(orderService.getAllOrders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

1. I know controllers should ideally have no logic. Is it appropriate for a controller to have this kind of authentication logic, or should the orderservice call the userAuthService directly?
2. How do I prevent this if(valid) then return ... else return ... from being duplicated in every CRUD function of the service deleteOrder, updateOrder, etc...

Comment: You could use SpringWebSecurity instead https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: 1. Its better to write a authentication filter which would intercept the calls before getting into the controller methods or you could write custom aspect say @Authenticated and annotate on top of your method.
2. If you have a http filter duplicate code would be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth having a look at *spring security* for **Authentication** and **Authorization** of requests.

However, if you want to keep it simple, I suggest handling the authorization logic in service layer. So, from your controller, calling `orderService.getAllOrders()` should be enough.

To avoid duplicating the `if else`, you can create a custom run time exception, and throw this from the service if authorization fails. You can have a global exception handler which takes care of returning the appropriate `HTTP status code` and `message`.

Refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If the project allows it, moving to spring security would be your best bet.
If not, I can offer you two options -

1.Using a preHandle interceptor, registering it for the needed endpoints.
You can access the request from the interceptor so implementing your validation logic from it should be possible. Also redirecting from an interceptor is possible.

Pro - simpler implementation

Con - no indication of this happening in the service

2.Using spring AOP, implementing a custom access control before annotation. You can have the request injetcted to get a hold of the required user id. You can't do a redirect from a before aspect, but you can define and raise an authorization exception, which you would handle in a gloabal exception handler and redirect from there.

Pro - Annotations clearly visible, easy to add or remove, can easily be made a method or class annotation

Con - more difficult implementation